# .NET sdk for acquiring song info from mp3 file (recognition)

Tags: .net, audio, sound-recognition

Is there an SDK/Web service for acquiring music information (artist, album, year, etc.) using an MP3 file as input? Something like android's Soundhound, but as an API for use with .NET

EDIT: Maybe, I wasn't so clear. Input: an MP3 file without any ID3 information. Output: the information of the song (acquired through recognition using a web service/database, like Soundhound or Shazam)

To be more specific. I need exactly what WinAmp does when you right click a song in the playlist --> view file info --> auto-tag

Comment: Do be clear, you don't mean the id3 info, you mean listening to the actual audio?

Comment: I think the answer is found [among these google hits](http://www.google.se/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=id3+.net). Especially [ID3.NET MP3 Tagging Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csid3lib/) looks promising.

Comment: There's also [taglib-sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp) from the mono project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to any metadata the only realistic way to get the information you want is to use a third party identification service. Most of these provide a .Net API but they are all commercial and you will therefore need to license their use.

Some examples:

- [Rovi](http://www.rovicorp.com/products/developers/innovate/rovi_cloud_services.htm?tabContent=/products/developers/innovate/rovi_cloud_services/testmnl_14378.htm)
- [Gracenote](http://www.gracenote.com/products/musicid/)
- [Landmark Digital](http://www.landmarkdigital.com/)